# Hide controller parameter in Swagger documentation

Tags: java, jersey, swagger

I'm using `swagger-jersey2-jaxrs` to generate `swagger.json`. This is my java code:

```
@Path("/example")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "object", required = true, dataTypeClass = MyObject.class, paramType = "body")
})
@ApiOperation(value = "Return one entity", notes = "Returns one entity at random", response = CommonResponse.class)
public String getStuff(String requestString) {...}
```

And I got this `swagger.json` file as the result:

```
"parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body", // SHOULD BE REMOVED
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "object", // I ONLY WANT THIS
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/MyObject"
            }
          }
        ]
```

As I know `String requestString` will generate parameter name="body" by default. How can I remove it? I just want my parameter name="object" to be appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `@ApiParam` annotation from `io.swagger.annotations` you can hide parameters. To do this, set the field `hidden` to `true`.

```
...
public String getStuff(
    @ApiParam(hidden = true) String requestString) {...}
```